# Mysql procedure, using parameter in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I made this procedure from phpmyadmin, but it don't works, I replaced the last word from **record_id** to a specified string id and worked, but when I use the parameter not working.

```
DROP PROCEDURE `prcd_update_record`;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
PROCEDURE `prcd_update_record`(
    IN `talep_id` VARCHAR(24), 
    IN `vall` INT(10)
) 
NOT DETERMINISTIC 
MODIFIES SQL DATA SQL 
SECURITY INVOKER 

UPDATE      `talep_malzeme` 
SET         `kalan_miktar` = vall
WHERE       `talep_malzeme`.`id` = talep_id;
```

The I execute it like this:

```
SET @p0='33'; SET @p1='57fb7911ea91e9efa'; CALL `prcd_update_record`(@p0, @p1);
```

Comment: What error you are getting? Add the error you are getting

Answer (score 1):

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `prcd_sevk_toplam`;
create procedure prcd_sevk_toplam(talep_id int, vall VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    UPDATE  `talep_malzeme` SET `kalan_miktar` = vall WHERE `talep_malzeme`.`id` = talep_id;
END;
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you has wrong parameter order, try

```
CALL `prcd_sevk_toplam`(@p1, @p0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should provide proper value to your parameter per your parameter definition. Your procedure accepts parameter as below

```
PROCEDURE `prcd_sevk_toplam`(
    IN `talep_id` VARCHAR(24), 
    IN `vall` INT(10)
```

And you are setting both of them to `varchar`. That could be the issue here. You should set them as

```
SET @p0=33; 
SET @p1='57fb7911ea91e9efa'; 
CALL `prcd_sevk_toplam`(@p1, @p0);
```